# How can I deploy my Telegram bot codes on my Ubuntu server?

Tags: telegram

I'm totally new to using VPS. Do I need to use SSH or FTP to deploy code files on it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either you deploy it via SSH or FTP it will work. Make sure you modify the permissions of the files. And you have required dependencies installed on server.